# Flutter app not updating automatically whenever new version is available on google play store

Tags: flutter, dart, updates, google-play-console, auto-update

I want the users of my app to always have the latest version. If they don't have the latest version, it should **download the latest version from play store automatically on app startup.** I'm using `in_app_update` for that. I'm performing `Performs immediate update`
Below is the code of splash screen which came after `main`. Here I check for update in `route` function, if update is available then perform update and navigate to `homeView`, If not simply navigate to `homeView`

But app never informed new user about update whenever new version is uploaded on playstore. They have to manually go to playstore to update an app. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong in a code or do I need to do something extra?

```dart
import 'package:in_app_update/in_app_update.dart';

class SplashView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashViewState createState() => _SplashViewState();
}

class _SplashViewState extends State<SplashView> {
  AppUpdateInfo _updateInfo;   // --- To check for update
  
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
  }

  startTimer() async {
    var duration = Duration(milliseconds: 1500);
    return Timer(duration, route);
  }

  route() async {
    await checkForUpdate();
    bool visiting = await ConstantsFtns().getVisitingFlag();
    if (_updateInfo?.updateAvailable == true) {
      InAppUpdate.performImmediateUpdate().catchError((e) => _showError(e));
          Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomeView(),
          ),
        );
    } else {
            Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomeView(),
          ),
        );
    }
  }

  Future<void> checkForUpdate() async {
    InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate().then((info) {
      setState(() {
        _updateInfo = info;
      });
    }).catchError((e) => _showError(e));
  }

  void _showError(dynamic exception) {
 _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content:
          Text("Exception while checking for error: " + exception.toString()),
    ));

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: AnimatedSplashScreen(
    .............................
      ),
   );
  }
  }
```

I don't know why suggested solution of similar question is not working for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62129373/7290043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By updating app itself without asking user is policy violation that may lead you to suspension of app. read this before trying anything like this: [Device and Network Abuse](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888379/)

You can ask users to update app whenever new update is available.

Edit:

code for Finding latest version on playstore:

```
getAndroidStoreVersion(String id) async {
    final url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$id';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      print('Can\'t find an app in the Play Store with the id: $id');
      return null;
    }
    final document = parse(response.body);
    final elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hAyfc');
    final versionElement = elements.firstWhere(
      (elm) => elm.querySelector('.BgcNfc').text == 'Current Version',
    );
    dynamic storeVersion = versionElement.querySelector('.htlgb').text;

    return storeVersion;
  }
```

For mobile version:
i have used this package [Package_info](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info)

To check if latest version is available or not:

```
getUpdateInfo(newVersion) async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    String playStoreVersion =
        await getAndroidStoreVersion(packageInfo.packageName);
    int playVersion = int.parse(playStoreVersion.trim().replaceAll(".", ""));
    int CurrentVersion=
        int.parse(packageInfo.version.trim().replaceAll(".", ""));
    if (playVersion > CurrentVersion) {
      _showVersionDialog(context, packageInfo.packageName);
    }
  }
```

You can design your pop up as per your convenience.

Comment: Yes @Mayur exactly. I know. I;m trying to show the prompt first as mentioned in `immediate update flow` this docs screenshot https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update
But I'm unable to show that prompt

Comment: @FaizanKamal i have updated my answer with code. as playstore doesn't provide any API here's a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for such a vital info. I only have one confusion now. If `(playVersion > CurrentVersion)` is true then how I'm gonna update app on "update" button click  of dialog inside if condition. Should I use URL launcher and send them to play store or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's recommended to use url launcher and send user to playstore let user update by their self.

Comment: I'm wondering if simply adding this line `InAppUpdate.performImmediateUpdate()` inside if condition of `playVersion > CurrentVersion` will actually work here and show me the full screen immediate update flow dialog or not? As shown here https://filebin.net/9loybs52eosb03ui/435dV.png?t=9cv2y3tf

   Above line came from this package https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update

Comment: And btw `newVersion` is used as the parameter of `getUpdateInfo` in above. Was it a mistake? If not, from where that `newVersion` came from?

Comment: And also in this line `final document = parse(response.body);`, I'm getting error `The method 'parse' isn't defined`

Comment: replacing `parse` with `json.jsonDecode` giving `FormatException: Unexpected character`

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help